# Android Chrome install banner a second time

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have this progressive web app working even with install banner, offline cache and push notifications.

Problem comes when you install it once, use it and remove it's shortcut from home screen.

How could I check if it is still working? Or how can I make it prompt again?

Is there a way to reset chrome on Android to ask for it again? "Clear & Reset" doesn't make it..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome 54 DevTools, the **Application > Manifest** tab has an **Add to homescreen** link that you could click to open the install banner on your [connected device](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, that is enough for what I need.

Comment: @HéctorMacías No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make the app install banner appear again is to enable a chrome flag:

**chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks**

[image: chrome flag bypass user engagement checks]

Comment: That would only make it appear first time. If you install and remove shortcut, it will never ask again for install prompt.